# Multiple Frameworks different targets XCode

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

If there are say 2 frameworks(framework-test,framework-live), one pointing to a test area and the other to live environment is there any way to keep both in the same xcode project and just change based on target or some flag?